# Acessing pointer makes its value change

Tags: c, pointers

I've been trying to write a little matrix framework in C. The problem is that acessing the matrix's components is modifying them somehow. You can see that the matrix `a` gets its elements changed in a weird way after being passed to `matrix_scalar_multiply`.

You can run the code at [jdoodle.com/a/13t7](http://jdoodle.com/a/13t7)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>


typedef struct Matrix
{
  int lines;            //number of lines
  int columns;          //number of columns
  float *numbers;       //elements of our matrix
} Matrix;

void
matrix_create (Matrix * a, const float *array, int lines, int columns)
{
  a->numbers = (float *) malloc (lines * columns);
  a->lines = lines;
  a->columns = columns;
  for (int i = 0; i < a->lines; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < a->columns; j++)
      *(a->numbers + j + i * columns) = *(array + j + i * columns);
}

void
matrix_init (Matrix * a, int lines, int columns)
{
  a->numbers = (float *) malloc (lines * columns);
  a->lines = lines;
  a->columns = columns;
}

float *
matrix_element (Matrix * a, int line, int column)
{
  return a->numbers + column + line * a->columns;
}

int
matrix_scalar_multiply (float scalar, Matrix * a, Matrix * answer)
{
  matrix_init (answer, a->lines, a->columns);
  for (int i = 0; i < answer->lines; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < answer->columns; j++)
      *matrix_element (answer, i, j) = *matrix_element (a, i, j) * scalar;
  return 0;
}

void
matrix_print (Matrix * a)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < a->lines; i++)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < a->columns; j++)
    printf ("%f   ", *matrix_element (a, i, j));
      printf ("\n");
    }
  printf ("\n");
}

#include <stdio.h>

int
main ()
{
  Matrix a;
  Matrix b;
  float aa[4][3] = { {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12} };
  matrix_create (&a, aa, 4, 3);
  matrix_print (&a);

  matrix_scalar_multiply (3.0, &a, &b);
  matrix_print (&a);
  matrix_print (&b);
  return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
1.000000   2.000000   3.000000   
4.000000   5.000000   6.000000   
0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   
0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   

1.000000   2.000000   3.000000   
4.000000   5.000000   6.000000   
0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   
0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   

3.000000   6.000000   9.000000   
12.000000   15.000000   18.000000   
0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   
0.000000   0.000000   0.000000
```

I've tried many things but couldn't find why **some** elements of matrix `a` are getting changed. If I comment   `matrix_init (answer, a->lines, a->columns);` everything goes fine. However, you can see that I don't even pass `a` as argument in `matrix_init`.

Comment: You're not mallocing enough space for your matrices.

Comment: @Shawn I've malloced lines*columns, shouldn't it be enough?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs And how big is a `float`?

Comment: `*(a->numbers + j + i * columns)` is customarily written as `a->numbers[j + i * columns]` in C.

Comment: @AndrewHenle so I should allocate `lines * columns * sizeof(float)`?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs Exactly. The argument to `malloc()` is in bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here.

```
a->numbers = (float *) malloc (lines * columns);
```

`malloc` allocates bytes, so this allocates `lines * columns` bytes. But `a->numbers` is an array of `floats` which are typically 4 bytes each. You've allocated only 25% of the necessary memory. When allocating memory for an array, you must also include the size of the elements.

```
a->numbers = malloc (lines * columns * sizeof(float));
```

(Side note: [it's unnecessary to cast the result of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc))

You can buy yourself a little more protection by using the size of `*a->numbers` instead. Then if the type of `a->numbers` changes, like to a `double *`, the allocation will still be correct.

```
a->numbers = malloc (lines * columns * sizeof(*a->numbers));
```